# How to sum up every nth line in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to output the sum of every N lines, for example, every 4 lines:

```
cat file
1
11
111
1111
2
22
222
2222
3
33
333
3333
```

The output should be:

```
6 #(1+2+3)
66 #(11+22+33)
666 #(111+222+333)
6666 #(1111+2222+3333)
```

How can I do this with awk?

Comment: If you want it in awk, why is bash in your title?

Comment: Can i use any language or just bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -vN=4 '{s[NR%N]+=$0}END{for(i=0;i<N;i++){print s[i]}}' input.txt
```

You can choose `N` like you wish.

*Output:*

```
6666
6
66
666
```

But you see, the output isn't sorted as expected when iterating through an `awk` array. You can fix this by shifting the line number by `-1`:

```
awk -vN=4 '{s[(NR-1)%N]+=$0}END{for(i=0;i<N;i++){print s[i]}}' a.txt
```

Output:

```
6
66
666
6666
```